# verilog code to find a single max value for an input that has 1000 samples values

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

i want to find a single max value for an input signal that has 1000 decimal values that is read from a memory once every Positive clk edge.  i did the following rough code for finding max value but it didn't give me the correct max value/number please help me so i can find a single max value in these 1000 values of input signal.

```
module(input clk, input [15:0]din, output [15:0]dout);
reg [15:0] max=0;

always @ (posedge clk)
if(din>max)
max<=din;
else
max<=0;

assign dout=max;
endmodule
```

Comment: You might use a **counter** to count 1000 samples. Currently, there is no provision for taking into account 1000 **latest** input values. Also, you need **store** those 1000 samples (memory). Each time the input changes (some combinational block), compare the present input with each of those 1000 samples.

Comment: As a side note, use non-blocking assignments (`<=`) in sequential blocks. Also, the keyword `posedge` needs to be in lower-case letters.

Comment: Sharvil111 thanks for your reply..if u don't mind can u edit my code  by writing code for counter to count these values and then i can find single max value..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assumption 1:**

If your memory read operation of 1000 valuation is out of your finding max value module then no need to track how many values are read.

```
module find_max (input         clk, 
                 input  [15:0] din, 
                 output [15:0] dout
               );

reg [15:0] max=0;

always @ (posedge clk)
begin
  if(din > max)
    max <= din;
  else
    max <= max;
end

assign dout = max;

endmodule
```

Your max value reflected in output after next cycle of being fed to `find_max` module.

**Assumption 2:**

If your outof `find_max` module not taking care of total number of valuation read then we just required one counter which track the number of cycles or valuation arrived.

```
module find_max (input         clk, 
                 input  [15:0] din, 
                 output [15:0] dout
               );

reg [15:0] max=0;
reg [ 9:0] cnt=0;

always @ (posedge clk)
begin
  cnt <= cnt + 1'b1;
  if(din > max)
    max <= din;
  else
    max <= max;
end

assign dout = (cnt == 10'd1000) ? max : 16'd0;

endmodule
```

We need not to store value of 1000 sample because we have to find only max value.

Comment: Prakash Darji..thanks for your time..i try yours code for my din signal but dout shows 0..it didn't maximum value.. i am attaching my test bench code plzz have a look on it..

Comment: upload your mem file

Comment: First try to read data from file.

See you are not fetching data from file properly, check it first and then see.

Comment: You haven't created clock also. make proper tb and then see the result.

Comment: @PrakashDarji. `reg [15:0] max=0;` is this valid ? I haven't come across double assignments for a reg ( max is also assigned inside always block). Can provide me any reference to read this ?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to assign a value to max when din<=max as in else statement.

`module(input clk, input [15:0]din, output reg [15:0]dout);
always @ (posedge clk)
if(din>max)
max<=din;
endmodule`

Comment: please upload hardware schematic of your code and my, and compare what it infer ?